# Using Nest for elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, highlighting, nest

Hi I'm using Nest as an interface to Elastisearch.
Everything works fine, there is only one thing I am unable to do.
And that is Highlighting.

I have the following 'model'

```
[ElasticType(Name = "WebResource", SearchAnalyzer = "full_name", IndexAnalyzer = "partial_name", DateDetection = true, NumericDetection = true)]
public class WebResource
{
    public string _id;
    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.integer_type, Index = FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)]
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            if (_id == null || _id == Guid.Empty.ToString())
            {
                _id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.string_type, Index = FieldIndexOption.analyzed)]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.string_type, Index = FieldIndexOption.analyzed)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I have an index and a search returns documents but the highlight is always zero

```
Client.Search<WebResource>(g => g.Query(k => k.Term(l => l.Content, searchText) || k.Term(l => l.Keywords, searchText)).Highlight(k => k.OnFields(p => p.OnField("Keywords"), p => p.OnField("Content")).FragmentSize(200)));
```

Where searchText is the searchtext.
Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards JR

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this question is related to 
[NEST (elasticsearch) Highlighting in multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361433/nest-elasticsearch-highlighting-in-multiple-fields)

My solution was to break it up in to a more readable form

```
Action<HighlightFieldDescriptor<WebResource>> actWeb = (t) => t.OnField(g => g.Content);
Action<HighlightFieldDescriptor<WebResource>> actKey = (t) => t.OnField(g => g.Keywords);

Action<HighlightDescriptor<WebResource>> higDesc = t => t.OnFields(actWeb,actKey);

SearchDescriptor<WebResource> searchdesc = new SearchDescriptor<WebResource>();

searchdesc.Query( t => t.Term( k => k.Content,searchText) || t.Term( l =>l.Keywords,searchText));                
searchdesc.Highlight(higDesc);

 var resp = Client.Search(searchdesc);
```

Turns out it's the way you combine the fields.

Comment: can you accept your own answer? Trying to keep the answered ratio on `nest` tag up :)